Onscreen keyboard keeps popping up
I updated to 24.04 months ago and everything worked fine until a a recent update since when whenever a text box appears, for instance for a password, an onscreen keyboard pops up. Since I am using a laptop with keyboard this is not only unnecessary but also extremely annoying.
How can I get rid of this annoying popup?

Maybe this helps: Run LANG=C gnome-control-center, select 'Accessibility' and check for 'Typing' that 'Screen Keyboard' is turned off (the switch is grey when turned off and orange-red when turned on).

gnome-control-center = 'Settings'
